# Finding average of n numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Everything is working except when the user types N to end the while loop, it doesn't go to the For Statement (this happens when you run the program, works fine in the shell and in the py).

```
potato = []
count = 0
avg = 0

question = input('Finding averages, continue? Y or N: ')
while question == 'Y' and count <= 12:
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    potato.append(num)
    count += 1
    question = input('Continue? Y or N: ')

for fries in potato:
    avg = sum(potato)/count
    print(fries,fries-avg)

print('average is: ' + str(avg))
```

Comment: do you get error message ? Show it in question.

Comment: Infinite loop? Not `break`?

Comment: This works fine for me, perhaps this is a python 2 -> 3 issue?

Comment: Seems to work... https://repl.it/Dswj

Comment: it works for me too

Comment: Tip:  `avg = sum(potato)/kount` does not need to be in the for-loop

Comment: In python 3 if you type `Y` you get the desired result in python 2 it tries to eval the value and complains about `NameError: name 'Y' is not defined
`. Of course this is a good example of why a complete question along with all error output is valuable.

Comment: why is avg calculated in the for loop?

Comment: Sorry guys, I guess I shoulda specified. Yeah, it's python 3. Also, there is no error coming. It just ends the program immediately without printing anything out. I'm not getting an error. On the shell and the py, it runs fine. When running the program, nothing.

Comment: It is very unclear what the differences are between "shell and py" vs "running the program"

Comment: When I double click the file to run it, that's what I mean by running the program. It runs as it should except when I type 'N'. When I type 'N', the for statement just completely doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

my_list=[]
val=int
sum1=int
n=int(input('Enter the limit:'))
for i in range(0,n):
    val=int(input('number:'))
    my_list.append(val)
sum1=sum(my_list)
print sum1
res=float(sum1/n)
print 'The average is:',res
```

Answer (score -3):

It was breaking for me until I changed the input to raw_input. Now it exits the while loop when input is not Y:

```
question = raw_input('Finding averages, continue? Y or N: ')
```

Comment: But question says "works fine in the shell and in the py". You aren't running Python3